# How to convert .aspx pages and master pages to html pages?

Tags: asp.net, html, master-pages

I am doing one project in asp .net.Its completed,then the same project will be done in html5. How to convert the .aspx pages and master pages to html 5? Is it possible?If any one know please tell me.

Comment: What do you mean by html5 page . For html5 we have new doctype and rest is how you will put the control

Answer (score 1):

You can technically make the page HTML5 by changing the `doctype`...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
```

It is also recommended that you specify a `lang` attribute on the `html` tag and include the `meta` tag to define your character set.

This won't give you instant HTML5 semantics, but this is essentially step one. Using the right elements for the right kinds of content will be down to you, for example deciding when to use `header`, `article`, `section`, `footer` instead of plain `div` elements and so on.

You should also be able to select "DOCTYPE:HTML5" from the toolbar in Visual Studio - I don't know what version you are using, but I think in the previous version you could download a HTML5 language extension, I'm pretty sure it is included by default in Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do... if I understand your question correctly is, rightclick and say view page source and copy your html or install google chrome and the on each page you can go rightclick and inspect element. you can copy and paste the html of each page including the masterpage content. Its a sloppy way but will work if you only want the html

Answer (score -1):

One of the way that i think you can do is to use http://modernizr.com/ kind of framework to switch between html5 and normal html easily .